# post record in chatter for account team Manually

Tags: chatter

Can anybody help me out how to post  record in chatter for account team manually. I  don't want the automated flow.
Thanx

Comment: Have you created a new tab using AccountTeamMember as an object ?

Comment: @Bennie no. actually i want to know how it is done  manulayy?  any workaround

Comment: When you say you want to post record in chatter for account team manually ? What exactly you mean?

Comment: individual user can post the record